# Android Studio Master/Detail Template Bug

Tags: android, android-studio

I am adding a Master/Detail Activity using the Gallery.

I set a login activity (also made from the Gallery) as it's parent (this is important or this piece of code won't be generated), and this line has an error:

```
 navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

If I add `import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;` and change the code to:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

it works.

**Is this a bug from the template or am I missing something here?** Because shipping code that wouldn't even compile doesn't sound much Google to me.

Comment: Big deal, if you've made it work, no big deal.

Comment: I don't agree... I made it work, but some beginners can struggle with something like this.

Comment: Is this from Android Studio 1.5.1 or 2.1 Preview 5?

Comment: 1.5.1 Build #AI-141.2456560

Comment: For shame, your SDK is fully updated? I know they just pushed some changes recently.

Comment: I updated it last night.

Comment: You could always do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33388205/1615876 - this in particular: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Tools%20bug%20report

Comment: done (11 chars to answer this)